# Bash : Check if file is sorted with sort -c file

Tags: bash, sorting

With

```
sort -c file
```

I received the first bad line that is unsorted as report, or nothing if the file is sorted. (And sort -c do not sort the file.)

I want to check if I received a report or not.
Something going like this :

```
if [ $(sort -c file) == *something* ]
then
    echo wasn't sorted
    sort file
    ...
else
    echo already sorted
    ...
fi
```

Is it possible, and how ?

Same question with -C instead of -c (if it's different or not with the "silent" option)...

Comment: Checking if sorted then sorting will take longer than just sorting it.

Comment: @dawg I know, in my case the check will be applied almost never...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if sort -C file; then
  # return code 0
  echo "sorted"
else
  # return code not 0
  echo "not sorted"
fi
```

Comment: As Cyrus has suggested, you need only check the exit code of the sort -C command.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the same concept, just with a little syntactic sugar.

```
sort -C file || echo -n "not " ; echo "sorted"
```

I prefer the format that Cyrus used, I just wanted to provide a fun version.

Here is a posix compliant version (as suggested by anishsane):

```
sort -C file || printf "not " ; echo "sorted"
```

Comment: It's for a full script project, so I don't need it but I see what you did there. Thanks

Comment: I am guilty that I too use `echo -n`, but just be aware that `echo -n` is not portable. Some versions of `echo` do not support `-n` and print it literally. When in doubt, use `printf "%s" "text"`, which is posix compatible.

Comment: This was perfect for putting in a `for` loop, thank you.